# ASP.NET AJAX - Check for async postback via JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

Does anyone know the script necessary to check to see if you are in a anync postback via JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to perform this check client side or server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I used the following which gave me the functionality I required:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._postBackSettings.async

Comment: `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()` is the public documented accessor and should be used instead. Thanks however, I didn't manage to find it before your post.

Comment: I know this post is 7 years old but do you know how to do this for ASP.Net 4.5? I tried the first one, but javascript crashes with Uncaught type error. The second method by Julien is just generates a squiggly line in the javascript method.

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries (jquery etc) set the X-Requested-With header to XMLHttpRequest so you could test for this in the request object, however you do not say your using msajax, jquery or custom script to do the xhr calls. If you give more detail I can advise better.

Other info [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2007/10/04/httprequest-using-isajax-amp-isjson-extension-methods.aspx) that may help you